# Docker unable to run Celery background task, Celery does not seem to start properly

Tags: reactjs, django, docker, redis, celery

I have created a project github repository that has Docker, Django, React, Redis, Celery:
https://github.com/axilaris/dockerize-django-react-celery-redis. My goal is to get celery working but its not.

This is based from this Docker - React and Django example tutorial code:
https://github.com/dotja/authentication_app_react_django_rest

And trying to use Docker - Celery & Redis from this tutorial code:
https://github.com/veryacademy/docker-mastery-with-django/tree/main/Part-4%20Django%20Postgres%20Redis%20and%20Celery <-- Part 4 tutorial for Celery & Redis

I am having trouble to get Celery started correctly as I see the background task is not executed. (you can check in my shared [gist](https://gist.github.com/axilaris/095b4fd926df6a27b5e635fc1b51c854))

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [mcve] directly in the question itself.

Comment: I'ved edited. You can easily check by using docker-compose build/up. Nothing fancy. I just want to get celery working properly in this example. I'ved tried it and I think its there but I think its incomplete with the celery logo and it doesnt product the prints for the worker when the task is being executed.

Comment: You don't seem to have included any source code in the question, only the output of various commands.  Without the source code it's hard to tell why you might be getting a "connection refused" error or any other problems.  This needs to be included directly in the question, not just via an external link.

Comment: The whole source code is in here: https://github.com/axilaris/docker-django-react-celery-redis. Mentioned at the beginning of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your files in github, you can do these: 
first, in your **init** file in "backend/backend/**init**.py", set this:

```
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ("celery_app",)
```

Set redis port in docker compose file and change your celery command:

```
redis: 
image: redis:alpine
ports:
  - "6379:6379"

celery:
restart: always
build:
  context: ./backend
command: celery -A backend worker -l info
volumes:
  - .:/django
container_name: celery  
depends_on:
  - redis
```

At the end you can set network for your docker compose, or check your docker log and the network.

You can also use this refrence: https://saasitive.com/tutorial/django-celery-redis-postgres-docker-compose/

```
web:
build: .
container_name: del_web
ports:
  - 8000:8000
volumes:
  - ./del_src:/del_src
command: bash Deployment/bashes/RunBash.sh
links:
  - db
  - redis
depends_on:
  - db
  - redis

redis:
image: redis
restart: always
volumes:
  - ./db/redis_data:/data
```

my RunBash.sh file is:

```
python3 -m celery -A del worker &

python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'ved update in github the code in docker-compose.yaml and backend/init.py. You can check my logs, I think it worked. https://gist.github.com/axilaris/2d1c69b4ac186fdac7e36a529e8f5cd2 One thing is for me to verify fully, how come I dont see the logs print on the background process just like in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zGtGliXMrPQ&t=1085s (start at 18:06). Also, it didnt appear like in my description the Celery logo (celery@b755a7cdba8d v5.3.6 (emerald-rush)). Can you let me know how to show those things also. I think it works right ?

Comment: I think for seeing your logs in the background your command should be DEBUG except info(you shouldn't do this in production). For your second question, I used to have a folder like: Deployment that has bash file and I add my command in that file.This is my architectural logic that I use in my projects, you can try it and if it is ok, use it in your project.
This is what I do and I can see the Celery logo when Docker containers come up.
At the bottom of my answer, I will edit and put what I did in Docker

Comment: I'm sorry, I still dont get it. I tried to put "python -m celery -A del worker &" to entrypoint.sh, and nothing change. I also think DEBUG may not be right for production. I have put up a bountry, hopefully I can get an answer for the github project I have posted. Thanks.

Comment: I will reward the bounty this. unfortunately, i still cant resolve the logo and see the background task logs.